# Will the data on my physical volume NOT deleted when creating a new Volume Group and Logical Volume?

Tags: linux, filesystems, system-administration, hard-drive

Basically my problem is mounting a logical volume which I posted on another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356555/how-to-mount-logical-volume.
The problem mainly lies on unrecognized volume group.
When running fdisk -l, one of the partition is clearly recognized as LVM.
And running pvs shows two existing physical volume.

Then I run into same problem on recovering the Volume create which just recreate the PV and create new VG.
So I got the idea of following that solution with some modifications
http://thuannvn.blogspot.com/2009/10/lvm-volume-group-recovery.html.
Since my PV is recognize, I'm thinking of just creating Volume Group and Logical Volume.

But I'm not quite sure if creating VG and LV will not delete from data/files on the physical I intend to add on the VG and LV.

Please help me guys. I have been researching for two days now.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The answer you got on that question is technically correct.

You can force an import of a volume dirty or not with the instructions posted to you in the link on how to mount a logical volume.

Honestly though, I'm paranoid about data loss. I would be certain you have imaged the drives off to scratch media before proceeding here.

Imaging the drives off as physical block devices to another drive will do two things, give you peace of mind, and it will read the entire surface during the copy. If issues exist (And I suspect they do) you will have to make several passes to get your data to image.

And if I'm wrong you will still have a copy of everything to save you from losing your data.

I'd use dd_rescue and image the underlying media before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

if the data is on the drive, extending or setting up a lvg and lvm on them will wipe the data out. be certain you have all your data in 2 other places before you begin.